# I would like to some calculation (minus two columns) for each row and then update the data back to to database but I am not sure how to do that?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Please help, the program suppose to take some inputs from user store in SQLAlchemy    database and do some calculation before list back to for user. I would like to query on each row targeting **the target column** and **the sample column** does some calculation and then **update the result directly to result column on database**. I am new to this thing I am sure  the problem is in the calculate function.

```
class Icecream(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'icecreams'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
    station = db.Column(db.Text)
    date = db.Column(db.Text)
    target = db.Column(db.Integer)
    sample = db.Column(db.Integer) 
    varience = db.Column(db.Integer) 

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def calculate():
        rows = Icecream.query.all()
        
        for row in rows:
            result = row.target + row.sample
            row.varience = result
            
       db.session.commit()
        
        return row.varience
    
    def __init__(self,station,date,target,sample,varience):
        self.station = station
        self.date = date
        self.target = target
        self.sample = sample
        self.varience = varience

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Index: {self.id} Station name: {self.station}\nDate: {self.date}\nTarget:  {self.target}\nSample: {self.sample}\nVariance: {self.varience}\n"
```